# egginfo error while installinh python package

Tags: python-2.7

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /tmp/pip-build-bAV0eg/ipython/

i seem to be getting this error while installing ipython library using pip on ubuntu,any suggestions how to fix this.

Comment: Are you using sudo ?

Comment: Check for a log file and look into it. Enable additional output during the installation attempt. If multiple installation attempts use the same directory, delete the directory before trying again.